# FloatingActionBar hidden under bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, floating-action-button, coordinator-layout

My fragment layout contains a CoordinatorLayout with a FloatingActionButton. The parent activity also contains a CoordinatorLayout with a PageView that brings in the fragment. The problem I have is that the FAB sits under the navigation bar instead of above it. It also moves up and down as I scroll the associated RecyclerView, whereas I want it to remain fixed. Here's the XML layout code for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faaversion4.ui.FAAMainActivity">

   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
           android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <include
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />

           <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
               android:id="@+id/tabs"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:tabMode="scrollable" />

       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
           android:id="@+id/pager"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="?colorPrimaryDark"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's the code for the toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

Finally, here's the code for the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/coordinator"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faaversion4.ui.cats.CatsFragment">

   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:columnCount="2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/breeds_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="50"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/gender_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="50"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/age_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="50"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/proximity_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="50"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="@string/distance"
            android:textAppearance="@style/MyTextAppearance" />

    </GridLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cat_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gridLayout" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab_add_cat"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As a workround I put a layout_MarginBottom on the FAB of 64dp but although it displayed it still moved up and down as the tab bar collapsed. Also, a generated Snackbar was also hidden under the bottom navigation bar. All the examples I've seen have the FAB and coordinator layout at the activity level, and without nesting of a further coordinator layout. Perhaps the only option is to put the FAB in the activity layout and access it from the fragments (e.g. hid it when not needed)? Thanks.

Comment: Try using android:clipToPadding=”false”

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a `ConstraintLayout` you should think about harnessing the power of it so that your UIs act accordingly. `ConstraintLayouts` help you remove the nesting of widgets and layouts. It makes them flatter, more readable, reducing code and making your app smoother.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs31620.faaversion4.ui.FAAMainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/breeds_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/gender_spinner"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/gender_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/breeds_spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/age_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/gender_spinner"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/breeds_spinner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/proximity_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/distance"
        android:textAppearance="@style/MyTextAppearance"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/age_spinner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/age_spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gender_spinner" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cat_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/age_spinner" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_cat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you didn't get the problem. because the container of the fragment and the bottom navigation are int he same layout and his fab is inside the fragment, then the fab is under the navigation view. My suggestion is to add use constraints but in the activity, not inside the fragment